# How does Ubuntu handle addition of RAM?

Tags: ram

I'm thinking of upgrading my laptop memory from 8gb ram to 16gb but I first would like to research how Ubuntu will handle it.

I already know that my laptop definitely supports adding more ram.

1. If I just insert more ram will I have to change anything in the OS or will it work/recognize it right away?
2. Will Ubuntu behave properly once I insert more ram (like will there possibly be errors or something that breaks my system or something)? Will it use all the ram (properly)?

My hope is that the addition will work right away (I'll shut it down while inserting it of course)  but first I'd like to how l know how Ubuntu will act.

Comment: As long as your hardware recognizes the extra RAM (ie. *no hardware issues or limits to what your hardware can utilize*) your Ubuntu OS will boot & use it without any required change.  I've stolen RAM from my secondary boxes for *testing* purposes and I make no change after I've stolen the RAM, or after it's returned.. The OS will use whatever RAM your hardware has available.

Comment: I would recommend running `sudo inxi -mx` to show you the speed, maximum size per slot and array capacity (max RAM) your motherboard will support.

Comment: you are only limited by what your systems hardware can handle.  So as long as your hardware supports memory expansion you can max out the memory on your system and Ubuntu will be fine with it.

Comment: I assume you aren't asking about adding it *while the machine is not shut down and powered off* because it seems to me like it could be read that way.

Comment: @Michael no I will shut down my pc before adding it 

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! Thanks to all the wonderful answers, I inserted more RAM and Ubuntu worked fine. It was just like that: I shut down Ubuntu, inserted RAM, and when I booted again, the settings app said I have 16GB RAM. Just like that! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I threw away the 8 GB RAM in my laptop and installed 32 GB of the best RAM available for my laptop. It was almost as good as installing the best NVMe SSD. Not a single problem as long as you go with High Quality manufacturer and the clock timing matches your motherboard.

**Respected RAM dealers will help you find a good match.**

Comment: How will I know if the ram will work with my laptop? What is a "good ram dealer" that will support my laptop and get the best identical match? Thanks in advance

Comment: @AlexFullinator What is the make and model of your laptop?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 17 3793

Comment: Also if it helps I already have one 8gib, 2667 mt/s speed, and DDR4 type memory device installed in the first slot (output of the command @Terrance sent)

Comment: @AlexFullinator I would classify Dell is a ***"Respected RAM dealer"*** especially when it comes to their own machines. I would go with the exact same RAM you have now for your second slot. You don't necessarily have to use mail order via Dell  You can take your laptop down to your local Best Buy who is an authorized Dell Reseller.

Comment: I went to the Dell website and I found one...but will Ubuntu still work with a memory card with a slightly different speed? (Original: 2667 MT/s | New: 2666 MHz)

Comment: @AlexFullinator To me it sounds like 2667 and 2666 are the same (2 and 2/3rds) with different rounding. The best guarantee is to open your laptop memory door and read the model number of the RAM in the slot. Then order the exact same RAM model number from Dell. For true peace of mind you can simply take your machine to Best Buy or another Dell Dealer and they will use technicians who ground strap their wrists, use anti static mats and test the RAM after installation.

Comment: A point to remember is Ubuntu can run on Internet Servers with Trillions of bytes of RAM. Your Dell and Mine are limited to maximum RAM of 32 Billion bytes or 64 Billion bytes.

Comment: Always a good idea to test your RAM after upgrading, but it's easy to do that yourself.  Boot into [memtest86+](https://www.memtest.org/) (packed in Ubuntu) and leave it running overnight, and do some [prime95 stress testing](https://www.mersenne.org/download/#stresstest) (a few hours or overnight).  Nothing will ruin your day like filesystem corruption from bad RAM occasionally flipping a bit in a buffer of disk cache, so I find it worth testing even though the chance of a problem is very low.  @AlexFullinator

Answer (score 23):

Assuming that the RAM works properly and is compatible with your hardware, Ubuntu will recognize and utilize the RAM without any interventions.

As far as compatibility: You might want to check your hardware's QVL to make sure that any new RAM is explicitly tested and supported.  Also, it's generally a good idea to install RAM modules in identical pairs.  Mismatched RAM can sometimes cause issues especially if they don't share timings and clock speeds.

Comment: If OP is using hibernation he may need to increase the size of the swap file.

Comment: The issue with mismatched RAM hasn't been a real problem for probably a decade. It can probably still happen with a bad bridge, but that's really rare and I haven't came across it for a long time.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't have a problem installing new RAM in Ubuntu as long as your motherboard supports it.

However, you might have to reset your CMOS, which just requires you to unplug the power cable on your computer, take out the CMOS battery for 5 minutes and then put it back in or shorting JBAT1 on your motherboard by connecting the pins with a screwdriver or using a jumper.

This shouldn't be necessary in 2022, but it is something I had to do when I added a new stick of RAM on an older motherboard this year.